# How do hormones influence personality?

Tags: emotion

I would like to see a specific type of answer to the question, namely, one that answers the following more specific questions: do hormones influence what people terminally value, that is, the things people as an end-in-itself? Or do hormones change people's emotional reactions to events, and since people are influenced by their emotions, this in turn influences their personality? Or do hormones bias people's world views, for example by making them think that being aggressive will be more or less successful at, say, getting someone to do what they want? Or do hormones affect a combination of these? Or do hormones affect something else entirely?

The material I have come across, for example [this](http://www.darionardi.com/BulletinArt9.html), describe what personality traits hormones influence, but not how they do so.